# Matching columns from one table with another

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Sorry for the confusing title, let me try to explain. The question relates to custom logging software where a company can design their own 'log'. Each log has a corresponding metadata table that has the columns from their log in it.

I am using php to render out a display of the data in the log. I first access the column names in the meta table and use that to build the table headers with a foreach as shown

```
foreach ($logStructure as $header)
{
   echo '<th>' . $header['label'] . '</th>';
}
endforeach;
```

Now I have done another select from the actual log for the rows to display and have that in an array call $logrow.
How do I go about iterating through those rows and putting the right data in the right column?
In SQl I would have used a WHERE Clause to say something to the equivalent of the following:

```
'WHERE $logrow['fieldname'] = $header['label']'
```

As an example the metatable fields look like this

```
[metaid] [columnLabel] [columnNameInData]
   001     Log Number       logNum
   002       Author        CreateUser
   003       Subject        Entry
```

The data gets put into the $header[] via a statement like such

```
SELECT columnLabel AS label FROM metatable;
```

The Log Structure Looks Like This

```
[logNum]  [CreateUser]       [Entry]
   001       Admin       Some Text about Stuff
   002      Editor 1     Another Amazing Entry
   003      Editor 2      It gets old by now
```

So the select looks like this

```
SELECT logNum, CreateUser, Entry FROM log
```

The data gets put into `$logrow['lognum'], $logrow['CreateUser'], $logrow['Entry']`

Hopefully this clears the question up a little better, I'm looking to match the column names in metadata with the values from those fields in the actual data.

Comment: Does the column names correspond? If yes then a loop and a new array should get you there. If not you may want to set up a separate sorting array to put them in the right order first.

Comment: yes they are in the same order, my problem is in the first array all the column headings are values under the 'label' key in the array, the second array, each key is its own name. i.e if the first field is recordNumber, it is stored in the first array as the first $header['label'] value, in the second array it's stored as header['recordNumber'] I'm trying to avoid hardcoded field names, so that different companies can setup different column names.

Comment: I think we need some example log table structures and data from metadata tables for this.

Comment: @user007 I added some additional info that I hope helps clear it up

Comment: What's the linking point of the `metadata` table with the `log` table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the sequence is gonna be always the same, and you are only trying to render it in the same table, I don't see what's stopping you to read both out into 2 separate arrays, then plot it onto the table.

First this:

`SELECT columnNameInData FROM metatable ORDER BY metaid;`

put the result into an array `$sort`

Then implode it and build your second select clause:

```
$columns=implode(', ', $sort);
$SQL="SELECT $columns FROM log";
```

And read the result into array `$result2`

Finally, assemble the header you have and the output of the $result2 as the rows and tds of logs, this table should have the records aligned with the headers.